# How can I go to the given URL in mobile Chrome browser using c# and appium on real device?

Tags: c#, android, webdriver, appium

I'm automating mobile web testing on Android real device with Appium and c#.
I've seen that there is get method in Java that allows navigation to the given URL, for example:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("device", "android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "chrome");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println("Android Title is: " + driver.getTitle())
```

I couldn't find such method in appium dot net driver.
Is it my mistake or there is no such method?
What is the best way to navigate then?

Here is C# code i use:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private DesiredCapabilities _capabilities;
        private AndroidDriver _driver;

        public void InitializeDriver()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Appium server");
            _capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            _capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Nexus One");
            _capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "300");
            _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
            _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "5.0.1");
            _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Android");

            //Application path and configurations
            _driver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), _capabilities);
        }
```

There is no _driver.Get() or _driver.SendKeys. What should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be found via Object Browser (this is what I did).
The analogue of Java code looks like:

```
_navigation = _driver.Navigate();
_navigation.GoToUrl(@"http://stackoverflow.com");
```

So the full listing will become this:

```
public void InitializeDriver()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Appium server");
    _capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    _capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Nexus One");
    _capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "300");
    _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Browser");
    _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "5.0.1");
    _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Android");

    //Application path and configurations
    _driver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), _capabilities);

    _navigation = _driver.Navigate();
    _navigation.GoToUrl(@"http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
driver.sendKeys(URL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, there is no SendKeys for _driver. Only this construction will work          _driver.FindElementById("someId").SendKeys("keys") and this is not exactly what I am asking for.