# force url to open in chrome:// Url with c# in Android

Tags: c#, android, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, url

I want to open a specific URL given with Application.OpenUrl() in a specific browser (chrome). Adding @"googlechrome://..." to the URL opens the browser but doesn't forward the URL. Any ideas to how force chrome to open the url?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917342/how-can-i-go-to-the-given-url-in-mobile-chrome-browser-using-c-sharp-and-appium) help you? it looks like the problem you're having.

Comment: no not really, since I'm using Unity. But thanks anyway